# MassTransit : Multiple Response Types and Headers

Tags: c#, request, masstransit

I have added an authorization filter in my pipeline that checks if user's token is valid.

So far, the token was added in the `Headers` of `SendContext` when sending a `Request`:

```cs
var response = await bus.Request<T1, T2>(remoteUri, data, timeout: requestTimeout,
    callback: o =>
    {
        o.Headers.Set(HeadersConst.AccessTokenKey, enveloppe.AccessToken);
    });
```

after checking the token, my filter throws an exception if an unauthorized access occurs. With this behavior, a fault is generated and the caller's request ends in timeout.

Now I want to move a step further by returning a special type of response with unauthorized accesses:

```cs
// In my filter when the token is invalid
await context.RespondAsync(new AuthorizationErrorResponse
    {
        Error = error,
        Message = message
    });
```

Consequently, I modified the caller's code:

```cs
IRequestClient<T1> client = bus.CreateRequestClient<T1>(remoteUri, requestTimeout);
var response = await client.GetResponse<T2, AuthorizationErrorResponse>(data).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Now this is where I'm stuck. I'd like to set the `Headers` as well but it seems like I can't when using the `IRequestClient` object. That's also why I was using the extension method `Request<T1, T2>` in the first place. If I try to modify the code and use `RequestHandle` instead, I can set my headers but I lose the multiple response type feature:

```cs
IRequestClient<T1> client = bus.CreateRequestClient<T1>(remoteUri, requestTimeout);
Response<T2, AuthorizationErrorResponse> response = default;
using (RequestHandle<T1> requestHandle = client.Create(data, token))
{
    requestHandle.UseExecute(o =>
    {
        o.Headers.Set(HeadersConst.AccessTokenKey, enveloppe.AccessToken);
    });

    // This call isn't supported by RequestHandle
    response = await requestHandle.GetResponse<T2, AuthorizationErrorResponse>(data).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Is there any workaround to achieve what I'm trying to do ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You could [look at the source](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/MassTransit/Clients/RequestClient.cs#L199) and create your own method, or you could wait for 7.2.3 which lets you configure the request similar to how you would using the handle.

You can see how `GetResponse<T>` is called multiple times, with `Task.WhenAny`.

Comment: Great thanks. Is the version 7.2.3 coming out anytime soon ?

Comment: It's currently available in pre-release packages.

Answer (score 0):

While waiting for the next release of MassTransit, this is the current solution to deal with my problem :

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Send a request and wait for multiple response types
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TRequest">Request type</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="T1">First type of response expected</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="T2">Second type of response expected</typeparam>
/// <param name="bus">MassTransit bus</param>
/// <param name="request">Request to be sent</param>
/// <param name="endpointUri">Endpoint Uri</param>
/// <param name="timeout">Communication tineout</param>
/// <param name="callback">Context setting callback</param>
/// <param name="token">Cancellation token</param>
/// <returns>One of the expected response types or timeout exception</returns>
public static async Task<Response<T1, T2>> GetResponse<TRequest, T1, T2>(this IBus bus,
                                                                        TRequest request,
                                                                        Uri endpointUri,
                                                                        RequestTimeout timeout = default,
                                                                        Action<SendContext<TRequest>> callback = null,
                                                                        CancellationToken token = default)
    where TRequest : class
    where T1 : class
    where T2 : class
{
    IRequestClient<TRequest> client = bus.CreateRequestClient<TRequest>(endpointUri, timeout);
    using RequestHandle<TRequest> handle = client.Create(request, token);

    if (callback != null)
    {
        handle.UseExecute(callback);
    }

    Task<Response<T1>> result1 = handle.GetResponse<T1>(false);
    Task<Response<T2>> result2 = handle.GetResponse<T2>();

    var task = await Task.WhenAny(result1, result2)
        .ConfigureAwait(false);

    await task.ConfigureAwait(false);

    return new Response<T1, T2>(result1, result2);
}
```

I'll update the answer once a cleaner solution comes up with the next release.